# Solr empty highlight entry on match?

Tags: solr

Hi i'm new in solr and have a problem with the highlighter.
The highlighter returns not for every match a highlight text, it works in most cases but not in all (see example the second entry).
Can anybody help me?

Solr Version: 7.4.0

Query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mpdv/select?hl.fl=mpdv_content_de&hl=on&q=mpdv_content_de:%22Dynamisches%20Anwendungsverhalten%22
```

Result:

```
  "highlighting":{
"y:\\MPDVAll\\ProductDocumentations\\de\\Procedures\\MDS_MOC\\MDS-Extensibility.pdf":{
  "mpdv_content_de":[" <em>Dynamisches</em> <em>Anwendungsverhalten</em>  \n\n• Spezifische Logik zur Sichtbarkeit/Aktivierbarkeit"]},
"y:\\MPDVAll\\ProductDocumentations\\de\\FunctionPackages\\MDS-BAS_8.1\\MDS-BAS_81.pdf":{}}}
```

Debugoutput:

```
 "debug":{
"rawquerystring":"mpdv_content_de:\"Dynamisches Anwendungsverhalten\"",
"querystring":"mpdv_content_de:\"Dynamisches Anwendungsverhalten\"",
"parsedquery":"PhraseQuery(mpdv_content_de:\"dynamisch anwendungsverhalt\")",
"parsedquery_toString":"mpdv_content_de:\"dynamisch anwendungsverhalt\"",
"explain":{
  "y:\\MPDVAll\\ProductDocumentations\\de\\Procedures\\MDS_MOC\\MDS-Extensibility.pdf":"\n11.151565 = weight(mpdv_content_de:\"dynamisch anwendungsverhalt\" in 2351) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.151565 = score(doc=2351,freq=2.0 = phraseFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    8.509058 = idf(), sum of:\n      2.1873097 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n        343.0 = docFreq\n        3060.0 = docCount\n      6.3217487 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n        5.0 = docFreq\n        3060.0 = docCount\n    1.3105522 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = phraseFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      1436.7814 = avgFieldLength\n      1688.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "y:\\MPDVAll\\ProductDocumentations\\de\\FunctionPackages\\MDS-BAS_8.1\\MDS-BAS_81.pdf":"\n1.0496296 = weight(mpdv_content_de:\"dynamisch anwendungsverhalt\" in 1372) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  1.0496296 = score(doc=1372,freq=2.0 = phraseFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    8.509058 = idf(), sum of:\n      2.1873097 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n        343.0 = docFreq\n        3060.0 = docCount\n      6.3217487 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n        5.0 = docFreq\n        3060.0 = docCount\n    0.123354375 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = phraseFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      1436.7814 = avgFieldLength\n      53272.0 = fieldLength\n"},
"QParser":"LuceneQParser",
"timing":{
  "time":9.0,
  "prepare":{
    "time":0.0,
    "query":{
      "time":0.0},
    "facet":{
      "time":0.0},
    "facet_module":{
      "time":0.0},
    "mlt":{
      "time":0.0},
    "highlight":{
      "time":0.0},
    "stats":{
      "time":0.0},
    "expand":{
      "time":0.0},
    "terms":{
      "time":0.0},
    "debug":{
      "time":0.0}},
  "process":{
    "time":8.0,
    "query":{
      "time":0.0},
    "facet":{
      "time":0.0},
    "facet_module":{
      "time":0.0},
    "mlt":{
      "time":0.0},
    "highlight":{
      "time":7.0},
    "stats":{
      "time":0.0},
    "expand":{
      "time":0.0},
    "terms":{
      "time":0.0},
    "debug":{
      "time":1.0}}}}}
```

Comment: try by adding hl.fragsize

Comment: Thanks, I try it, but highlight is empty on second entry:
http://localhost:8983/solr/mpdv/select?debugQuery=on&fl=id&hl.fragsize=500&hl.fl=mpdv_content_de&hl=on&q=mpdv_content_de:%22Dynamisches%20Anwendungsverhalten%22

Comment: then you might need to try with more fragment size or try some of the option from https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/highlighting.html

Comment: Thanks Abhijit for your hint! the solution was the parameter hl.maxAnalyzedChars. I think while the text field is very big in this case

Solution Query:
http://localhost:8983/solr/mpdv/select?debugQuery=on&fl=id&hl.maxAnalyzedChars=500000&hl.fl=mpdv_content_de&hl=on&q=mpdv_content_de:%22Dynamisches%20Anwendungsverhalten%22

Comment: Welcome.Do you want me add it as an answer..?

Comment: Yes, but i can't mark a comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `hl.maxAnalyzedChars` in the query in order to get the highlighted text.
You can increase the value of maxAnalyzedChars.

`hl.maxAnalyzedChars` : The character limit to look for highlights, after which no highlighting will be done. This is mostly only a performance concern for an analysis based offset source since it’s the slowest. The default value is 51200.

For more information on the highlighting please refer the below link

[Solr Highligheting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/highlighting.html)

Comment: Thanks,Abhijit Bashetti!